# Scroll functionality in appium to idetify specific object in List box/dropdown

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I have a list box where all the states of India is listed and i need to select a specific state using scroll.

Tried Touchactions
Tried Java script executor

```java
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
AndroidElement sct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='Karnataka']"));
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",sct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a little bit wrong, you cannot use [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) when it comes to [Appium](http://appium.io) tests as you're limited to a specific list of [Mobile Commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) Appium can understand.

You need to refactor your code to use [`mobile:shell` command](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/), something like:

```
Dimension windowSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("command", "input");
args.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("swipe", windowSize.width / 2,
        windowSize.height / 2, windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height));
while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='Karnataka']")).size() == 0) {
    driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@text='Karnataka']")).click();
```

Alternatively you can use [SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SwipeWhileNotFound) command available via [SeeTest Appium Extensions](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension)

```
seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Up", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "xpath=//android.view.View[@text='Karnataka']", 0, 1000, 5, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Appium doesn't have any direct method for Scroll
2. By using the AndroidUiAutomator locator and new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(tag(/"value/")) You can scroll upto element.

Try with below code:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(tagName(\"value\"));");
```